# Tidying time series data

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe\matrix with dates in column and the hours in the rows. How can I rewrite the data in a dataframe with the time series in date and hour in a column and its respective recorder in another one ?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that your data is like this and has name df

```
hour    2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03
06:00   abc             def         ghj
07:00   klm             nop         qwe
08:00   rty             hjk         mnb
09:00   klp             ghm         asd
```

you can use melt from reshape2 library.

```
install.packages(reshape2)
library(reshape2)

reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "hour")
```

which will give this 
(no matter that your receptive recorder is numeric or character)

```
hour   variable   value
06:00 2018-03-01   abc
07:00 2018-03-01   klm
08:00 2018-03-01   rty
09:00 2018-03-01   klp
06:00 2018-03-02   def
07:00 2018-03-02   nop
08:00 2018-03-02   hjk
09:00 2018-03-02   ghm
06:00 2018-03-03   ghj
07:00 2018-03-03   qwe
08:00 2018-03-03   mnb
09:00 2018-03-03   asd
```

Comment: It works, i just mase some adaptations